# Regular Expression to allow only 0-9 digits only (Not even '.' [Dot]) in JSP using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, jsp

Could anyone please provide me with a regular expression to allow only digits (0-9) excluding even '.' (decimal point) in a textbox in JSP using javascript. I would be using it to replace the resricted characters with '' (empty string).

I tried few but they are not restricitng the DOT.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the regex you are using right now?

Comment: use [0-9]* i dunno how to write in jsp but use this as regex in jsp

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/ will help..wat u want is very basic

Answer (score 4):

regex pattern would be:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex:

```
/^\d*$/
```

to make sure that the *entire string* consists of digits.

Without `^` and `$`, the regex would match `1` (and `234`) in `1.234`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the class `\d`, it includes only digits. If you want to replace all non-digits you would need to replace `\D+` with `""`.

Comment: @Esailija - Here is what I am using in my javascript function -    textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(/[^\0-9.+$/i, "");

Comment: Try `.replace(/\D+/, "")`. You missed a closing `]` in your code, there is also a backslash infront of the 0 and a dot after the 9.